# Cannot run bundle install on DigitalOcean Ubuntu Ruby on Rails on 14.04 (Postgres, Nginx, Unicorn) droplet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, digital-ocean

I tried to bundle install my gems on DigitalOcean via root ssh.
after i logged into the server via root and cloned my repo into rails folder, then i tried to run bundle install then i always got this

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
.
.
.
Using thor 0.19.1
Killed
```

Never finished.
So anyone knows how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot that can cause something like that. Could be the bundle is failing due to resource issues. Could be it is failing to retrieve a gem file. Sadly, you would need to provide more information.

I would recommend trying to install the gem files needed in your application manually one by one to see if you can locate the gem that is failing. If none of them fail, it is likely a resource usage issue occurred when bundler was doing its thing.

Comment: i can successfully gem install thor but still get stuck in the same line of bundle install.

Comment: Right, it might not be Thor failing. Could be any of them gems, or a combination of them. It could also be resources. Might want to check sar logs or the like to see how your droplet reacted when you did the bundle install. Hard to say without digging into it more. If you already have Thor in your gems, try re-running bundler.

Comment: it seems like my hosting plan doesn't have enough memories.
thanks!